# Get the all Fields value from Netsuite on a particular Record Using WSDL or SOAP

Tags: c#, wsdl, netsuite

I would like to get the all fields details from Netsuite on a particular Record due to created time.I will try to add the New Record and Based on Input Field and set the input fields value via web services.

for example :
we want to add a new user to Netsuite using web services.But I don't know what are the custom's fields available there.

If you have any solution about this scenario, Kindly share with me.

Thanks ,
Somu

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want to reference the Schema Browser for the available fields and their ID's available to web services. You can access that page [here](https://system.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/srbrowser/Browser2016_1/schema/record/employee.html).

Answer (score 0):

if you are talking about **Contact** or **Customer** custom fields, you can do it this way:

- getting custom fields list;
- getting fields details and checking if the fields Applies to entity ;

  ```
    CustomizationType ct = new CustomizationType { getCustomizationType = GetCustomizationType.entityCustomField, getCustomizationTypeSpecified = true};

    var getCustIdResult = svc.getCustomizationId(ct, false);

    ReadResponseList readResp = svc.getList((CustomizationRef[])getCustIdResult.customizationRefList);

    foreach (var customField in readResp.readResponse.Select(r => r.record))
    {
    // here we have all details of custom field
        if (customField.appliesToContact && customField.appliesToContactSpecified)
        {
            //do something
        }
        if (customField.appliesToCustomer && customField.appliesToCustomerSpecified)
        {
            //do something
        }
    }
  ```